# add class to item in array and remove others

Tags: javascript, arrays

im trying to achieve something pretty simple. i have a list of items. if i click on one it should give it a class of selected. however if i click on another item in the list. it should remove the selected class from the previous element. this is my javascript code.

```
const timeRangeWrapper = document.querySelector('.time-range');
const timeOptions = timeRangeWrapper.querySelectorAll('.times .time-option');
    timeOptions.forEach((item, i) => {
        const domIndex = item.getAttribute('data-item');
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (i == domIndex) {
                item.classList.add('selected');
            } else if (i !== domIndex && item.classList.contains('selected')){
                item.classList.remove('selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

this is my markup

```
<div class="time-range">
    <span class="helper">Please select an exact booking time</span>
    <ul class="times">
        <li class="time-option" data-item="0">7.00PM</li>
        <li class="time-option" data-item="1">7.15PM</li>
        <li class="time-option" data-item="2">7.30PM</li>
        <li class="time-option" data-item="3">7.45PM</li>
        <li class="time-option" data-item="4">8.00PM</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="btn-wrapper form text-center mt-15">
       <button data-accept="true" data-time-exact="false" class="btn booking btn-custom-primary text-small bold text-uppercase">Confirm</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: you're looping over the items for the bindings, but there is no scenario in which  `i !== domIndex` when clicking it.

Answer (score 2):

You can firstly remove `.active` class from all `options`, then add class to specific one that was clicked:

```js
const timeRangeWrapper = document.querySelector('.time-range');
const timeOptions = timeRangeWrapper.querySelectorAll('.times .time-option');
    timeOptions.forEach((item, i) => {
        const domIndex = item.getAttribute('data-item');
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            timeOptions.forEach(option => {
              option.classList.remove('selected');
            })
            if (i == domIndex) {
                item.classList.add('selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="time-range">
    <span class="helper">Please select an exact booking time</span>
    <ul class="times">
        <li class="time-option" data-item="0">7.00PM</li>
        <li class="time-option" data-item="1">7.15PM</li>
        <li class="time-option" data-item="2">7.30PM</li>
        <li class="time-option" data-item="3">7.45PM</li>
        <li class="time-option" data-item="4">8.00PM</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="btn-wrapper form text-center mt-15">
        <button data-accept="true" data-time-exact="false" class="btn booking btn-custom-primary text-small bold text-uppercase">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

DOM manipulation is much easier with jQuery:

```
const $items = $(".times .time-option");

$items.on("click", function() {
  $items.removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

[Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/qauu7fk5/)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate function that removes the class from the selected items first, then adds the selected class to your item.

```
const timeRangeWrapper = document.querySelector('.time-range');
const timeOptions = timeRangeWrapper.querySelectorAll('.times .time-option');
    timeOptions.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            removeSelected(timeOptions);
            this.classList.add('selected');
        });
    });

function removeSelected(items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove('selected');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const timeRangeWrapper = document.querySelector('.time-range');
const timeOptions = timeRangeWrapper.querySelectorAll('.times .time-option');
let currentSelected = null; // Store the current selected LI
timeOptions.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
                if (item !== currentSelected) {
                    if (currentSelected) {
                        currentSelected.classList.remove('selected');
                    }
                    item.classList.add('selected');
                    currentSelected = item;
                }
                // else we do nothing, it means it is already selected.
    });
});
```

Don't use the "DomIndex" variable. Prefer this way, it is more readable and reliable.
On click, we test if the one clicked is not the one already clicked.
Then if there is an LI already selected, we remove its ".selected" and give it to the new one.

All the other solutions loops on each "LI" to remove a potential ".selected"... it is useless and could be much longer.